# How to know which apps to shutdown when there is overheating?

Tags: macbook-pro, activity-monitor, temperature

I once unfortunately closed a program that I found in the Activity Monitor to be using a lot of resources. A bit of Context: that day my macbook pro was suddenly heating up like crazy and the usually silent fan started blaring up! So I guessed that it was the root of all the trouble and force-quoted it, only to be subject to a screen of death notification!

So, in order to avoid this, I ask you to help me to be a better judge of the applications for situations as these!

Comment: Do you have the Firefox browser installed?

Comment: I do have Firefox installed. And i shutdown one of the processes that were in the top. The processes are listed according to the amount of resources they use up.

Comment: The latest version of Firefox has some problems leading to high cpu usage (fans spinning)

Comment: Thanks, that just explains a lot! Firefox was indeed in my foreground that day!

Answer (score 1):

The recent Firefox release (32) has a tendency to run in to conflict resulting in very high CPU consumption. That leads to high speed fans.

Mozilla has released a fix (32.01), but the results are yet to be seen.

Comment: Ok, so can I be decently sure that all software I have that are from other developers (not from apple) may be the cause for the issues related to heating? I'm trying to eliminate a set of possibilities here to focus on apps that may be the potential causers for the problem.